# Java Casting ArrayIterator<Object>

Tags: java, casting

The queryMe method returns an ArrayIterator<Me>. The queryYou method returns an ArrayIterator<You>.

```
public ArrayIterator<Object> query(String table, String field, String criterion)
{
    ArrayIterator<Object> result = null;

    if (table.equals("MyTable")
    {
        result = MyTable.queryMe(field, criterion);
    }
    else if (table.equals("YourTable")
    {
        result = YourTable.queryYou(field, criterion);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm getting an error that says

```
ArrayIterator<Me> and ArrayIterator<Java.lang.object> are incompatible types.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As error says, I think you should create and return ArrayIterator with type <Me> instead of returning ArrayIterator with type object

Comment: That method is much more complicated than that, it has many other if statements. For purpose of simplicity, I only posted one. I'm about to edit it now.

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding of generics to think that ArrayIterator<Me> is a subclass of ArrayIterator<Object>, since Me is a subclass of Object.  But it just does not work that way.  Any tutorial on generics can explain why.

Comment: What would I have to do to fix the problem? I tried, making the method return ArrayIterator<T> but that wouldn't work. This class has only static methods and Java doesn't allow you to reference T from a static context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the hack you're after.  Cast it to a raw ArrayIterator first and then to ArrayIterator<Me>.

ArrayIterator<Me> meIter = (ArrayIterator) result.

The better way is to change your method to return ArrayIterator<Me> and change result to the same.

***Just saw your update.  It appears that the method is trying to return ArrayIterators of varying types, hence the <Object> return type.

```
// Would be nice if the 2 types shared a common super type.   
public ArrayIterator<Object> query(String table, String field, String criterion)
{
    // WARNING, this is a raw generic type, and provides no type safety
    ArrayIterator result = null;

    if (table.equals("MyTable")
    {
        result = MyTable.queryMe(field, criterion);
    }
    else if (table.equals("YourTable")
    {
        result = YourTable.queryYou(field, criterion);
    }
    return (ArrayIterator<Object>) result.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not cast it because `ArrayIterator<Me>` is not subtype of `ArrayIterator<Java.lang.object>` in fact, these two types are not related.

[Find more explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can't convert `ArrayIterator<Me>` to `ArrayIterator<Object>`, you should change returning type of `queryMe` function 
but if you're iterator always has type `Me` it's be better to use `ArrayIterator<Me>` in whole of your program